# Is still necessary using the Add-on Ifelse from Mark Croxton with EE2.9?

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

In the new EE version (2.9), the conditionals evaluate when ready, so the performances are boosted.

Is still necessary using the IfElse Add-on from Mark Croxton, when using EE conditional?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet, but in theory it shouldn't be necessary anymore since conditionals all have the same behavior in EE now. And I wonder about routes substituting switchee in many cases too.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, for the moment I didn't used yet the routes inside EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If you aren't using variables on conditional outside the default order, you can remove ifElse.

For example, ifElse parses early variables like `member_id` and `group_id`.

Take some time to look at the [parsing order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html) and see if you need to change it in some way.

Comment: Thanks Robson about the parsing order information. I I had forgotten this parameter.

Comment: I'm curious to know if i continue using ifElse without necessity (variables not used on conditional outside the default order) , the performance would be influenced or not ?

Comment: Usually, less add-on, better the performance, except when the add-ons are intended to cover a performance flaw. For example, Stash can make the performance better or worst. Depended on how it is used.

Comment: yes, thanks!! the new conditionals in EE 2.9 are nice.